# ¿Cómo puedo voltear una matriz de dos dimensiones 90°?

Tags: array, c, matrices

**Estoy utilizando lenguaje C.**
Esta parte es el código que estoy utilizando para abrir el archivo, cada carácter de la imagen se está guardando en una matriz.

```
#define TAM 128
void leerArchivo() ;
void imprimirArchivo( int m[TAM][TAM] ) ;
void rotarMatriz( int m[TAM][TAM] ) ;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int m[TAM][TAM] ;
    leerArchivo() ;
}

void leerArchivo() {
    
    int m[TAM][TAM], i, j ;
    FILE * archivo ;
    archivo = fopen( "clubDeAlgoritmia128x128invert.txt", "r + t" ) ;
    
    for( i = 0 ; i < TAM ; i++ ) {
        for( j = 0 ; j < TAM ; j++ ) {
            fscanf( archivo, "%c", &m[i][j] ) ; 
        }
    }
    fclose( archivo ) ;
```

Comment: Para rotar una matriz te puede ayudar esta entrada https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42519/how-do-you-rotate-a-two-dimensional-array

Comment: Los 90 grados ... ¿sentido horario o antihorario?

Answer (score 0):

Hay muchas maneras de rotar una matriz de datos 90º, lo que yo creo que es más sencillo es recorrer la matriz de izquierda → derecha y de arriba → abajo mientras copias en otra matriz de derecha → izquierda y de arriba → abajo:

```
int matriz[3][3] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
int copia[3][3] = {};

for (int y = 0; y != 3; ++y)
{
    for (int x = 0; x != 3; ++x)
    {
        copia[x][2 - y] = matriz[y][x];
    }
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nU9bbsIwEPy2TzFQVUqEqRJS@krpDXoC6g8rAWqJ2sgYKSnK2dMNpgl8Vao00mp2Z3dnimmxVWbTtjfaFNtDucLr3pfa3n2@ca6Nx5fSJor5kbPAvNPfy0wSsMARiUAqMBPIBO4F5gIPAo8CT2jysFLYnVbDBrU5W1uHqBvW1EpyKqMFshyTSR1zxnaOZutofFvihA8zFr@va7lM5CVLr9hMxn8/oDCDogqKqldUnYVOwoL1iq5iirqzPzyqJOVjDSfw3vD7aQxnvSoVnhNsnCrt/oUCxP/NHUycY/ckvSTn0G7lD87QXd607Q8)</kbd>.